# Calling onNewIntent() from a notification

Tags: android, android-intent

MainActivity hosts all of my fragments.

I need to display one particular fragment when the user clicks on a Notification that was received from *Google Cloud Messaging*.

I was under the impression that I could handle this from **onNewIntent()**, but this method doesn't seem to fire after I press the notification.

Here's my send notification method in my **GcmIntentService** class:

```
private void sendNotification(String message, String eventId) {

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(Constants.eventIdBundleKey, eventId);

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_test)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(message))
                    .setContentText(message);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

}
```

and here in MainActivity, where I'm trying to receive and process:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);


    if(intent.hasExtra(Constants.eventIdBundleKey)) {

        Fragment fragment = GiftsPriceFragment.newInstance(Common.retrieveAppUser(this), null, null);
        mFm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(GiftsPriceFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();

    }

}
```

---

Any idea why onNewIntent() doesn't get called?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try setting `launchMode of your activity as  "singleTop"` in manifest.

From Official documentation.

This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in their package, or if a client used the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag when calling startActivity(Intent). In either case, when the activity is re-launched while at the top of the activity stack instead of a new instance of the activity being started, onNewIntent() will be called on the existing instance with the Intent that was used to re-launch it.

An activity will always be paused before receiving a new intent, so you can count on onResume() being called after this method.

Note that getIntent() still returns the original Intent. You can use setIntent(Intent) to update it to this new Intent.

Comment: Ah ok, looks like I did indeed need that singleTop in my manifest, and also call setIntent(). Now my only issue is that I can't seem to retrieve the string that I sent, it comes up null in onNewIntent()?

Comment: You are not trying to retrieve that string at all. Maybe you ment to say that hasExtra() returns false?

Comment: I have the same code but it doesn't works. Have you succeeded?